# how to use mxNumericArray

Tags: matlab, mex

My goal is to return a UINT32 number:

I have been using `mexCreateDoubleScalar` and I would like to change it to `mxCreateNumericArray`

The old code is

```
const int ALL_GOOD   0;
plhs[0]=mexCreateDoubleScalar(ALL_GOOD);
```

The new code i want

```
const int ALL_GOOD   0;
int dim[2];
dim[0]=dim[1]=1;
plhs[0]=mxCreateNumericArray(2,dims,mxUINT32_CLASS,mxREAL);
```

How can I put the value `ALL_GOOD` in `plhs[0]`,
Or any batter way to return `UINT32` from mex?

Comment: OK.  Seeing as your "old" code doesn't have a chance of compiling, I'm guessing you don't have or haven't looked at a compiler error for the new code.

Comment: this isnt copy paste
i cant copy the code, i just asking for the idea of doing it,
the old code did work (got duable back to my matlab function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mxCreateNumericMatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatenumericmatrix.html) which is slightly more simple than the general `mxCreateNumericArray` to create the container `mxArray`, then use [`mxGetData`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetdata.html) to get a pointer to the actual memory of the allocated scalar and assign the value to it.

```
const int ALL_GOOD = 0; // need assignment here...
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix( 1, 1, mxUINT32_CLASS,mxREAL); // create the scalar
unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)mxGetData( plhs[0] );
ptr[0] = ALL_GOOD; // assign the value to plhs[0]
```

Comment: sounds great, will go to the machine and try it out